# Error generating builder APK on Android Studio

Tags: ggh4x

When you configure the apk file of the Android Studio program this appears etc.

Is there a solution to this problem knowing that I am working on a source code called `newsfreak`?

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard.doOKAction(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:154)
    at com.intellij.ide.wizard.AbstractWizard.proceedToNextStep(AbstractWizard.java:237)
    at com.intellij.ide.wizard.AbstractWizard$5.actionPerformed(AbstractWizard.java:199)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:270)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6654)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5029)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2793)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:898)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:820)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:743)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:439)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:803)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:438)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:106)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:604)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:436)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:873)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:484)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1070)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:702)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:439)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1656)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1614)
    at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard.show(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:167)
    at org.jetbrains.android.actions.GenerateSignedApkAction.actionPerformed(GenerateSignedApkAction.java:62)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.lambda$performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks$4(ActionUtil.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:256)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$performAction$0(ActionMenuItem.java:289)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:233)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.performAction(ActionMenuItem.java:281)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:296)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$2(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:106)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:95)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:540)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:570)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6654)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5029)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2793)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:898)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:820)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:743)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:439)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:803)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:438)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:119)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:604)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:436)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:873)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:484)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please refer to [how do I write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question quality.